# Need to convert following string into time format

Tags: c#

I have the following two dates in string format.

```
1. 06 Mar 2013 
2. 26 Mar 2013
```

I need to compare those two dates i.e `if (06 Mar 2013 < 26 Mar 2013)`

Is there any built-in function to convert string into C# Date and Time format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to parse these two dates to DateTime Object, using [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx) with format `dd MMM yyyy` and then compare both.

```
string str1 = "06 Mar 2013";
string str2 = "26 Mar 2013";

DateTime dt1 = DateTime.ParseExact(str1, "dd MMM yyyy", null);
DateTime dt2 = DateTime.ParseExact(str2, "dd MMM yyyy", null);
if(dt1 < dt2)
{
  //dt1 is less than dt2
}
```

You can also use the format `d MMM yyyy`, with single `d` which would work for both single digit and double digit day (e.g. `02` ,`2` and `12` etc)

Comment: Thanks Mate... I was stuck with this part for sometime...:)

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is. Try `DateTime.Parse` and `DateTime.ParseExact` methods. Here is the code sample:

```
string first = "06 Mar 2013";
string second = "26 Mar 2013";

DateTime d1 = DateTime.Parse(first);
DateTime d21 = DateTime.Parse(second);

var result = d1 > d21; //false
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `DateTime.ParseExact` in the following way:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(str, "dd MMM yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/TajE3L)

`CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` is needed to ensure that it will be parsed successfully even if the current culture does not have english month names.